# Is there a machine learning StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, machine-learning

Is there a research-level machine learning site in the StackExchange universe? I don't like Reddit's formatting system.

Comment: [stats.SE] is an SE Q&A site for machine learning questions.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, as already said in @gung's comment, [CrossValidated *is* the site to ask questions on machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Many machine learning questions (mostly those that focus on coding issues) are also [asked and answered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[machine-learning]).

Moreover, if you search [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), you'll see that there were already two proposals for "Machine Learning" sites, but **they were closed** mostly because of small traffic and a small number of active users.

[image]

Additionally, there is also a [Data Science SE site](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), that has very similar scope to Cross Validated. [We discussed it many times](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=data%20science). The general conclusion of users of Cross Validated is that the Data Science site is redundant given Cross Validated, so  the same would apply to any Machine Learning site.

Comment: There is also the IBM sponsored [Artificial Intelligence SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/).